# Codeigniter not recognizing my database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have seen tutorials and searched across internet but my issue is still there, "codeigniter saying (test.user_accounts) doesn't exist". I have created a db named "test" at phpmyadmin and searched it from my terminal and got the result I put in it, also I changed database.php file in config and did add localhost, root, "mypassword" and "test" as hostname, username, password, database.

All the credentials are correct as I do login with them from my terminal to the mysql interface.

```
$this->load->database();
$q=$this->db->query("Select * from user_accounts");
print_r($q);    //prints that no such table as test.user_accounts
```

But I can see the table and values in it from phpmyadmin and my terminal. Any possible solution for this head-scratching problem is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table does not exist response should mean that you are connecting to the database and your query is being executed, all of which is quite good.

Maybe try to simplify the problem, keep isolating it. Perhaps try a table that should always exist like dual, eg: `select 1 from dual`. It could be that you are not 'using' any current database, almost a namespacing problem, try: `select * from test.user_accounts`

Comment: Still no luck, btw if I do "select * from user_accounts" from phpmyadmin I do get my result, doesn't it mean that codeigniter can't find the db test?

Comment: I suspect so. Using an explicit DB prefix on the table name, eg: `test.user_accounts` should help determine if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve read about your problem, and i think it´s just a little thing you should have missing.

Really, your code so far, is correct, but give another look at you database config.

There are only 4 lines, we used to change

```
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'test',
```

Maybe you repeated some of them, or just inverted the values.

At last, it could be just a letter or something misspeling, like account, wrote correct at php_admin and wrong with on only "c" saved at your application.
Use copy and paste always to make sure.(of course you´d probably did that)

No matter how experienced we are, always these things can happens.